# How to pass data from an activity to dialog what is the java code for this?

Tags: android, android-activity

[How to pass data from one activity to another activity, what is the java code for this?][1]

<[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dl3r.png>

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/3308320) should help with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

save result in string and then
create a method with one parameter to make dialog, like this
and in button's onclick call that method.

```
public void (String res) {

AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
dialog.setTitle("test");
dialog.setMessage(res);

dialog.show();
```

}